# How to bind a JavaFX Label to the selected item from a ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2, javafx

I have a ListView full of POJOs and want a label in the GUI to display informations from the selected item.

My POJO looks something like that:

```
class Customer {
  private String name;
  ...
  public String getName() {
  return name; 
  }
```

Now when the user selects a customer from the list I want the name of the selected customer displayed in a label.

Obviously I can't bind to the `name` directly because it is not a `Property`. (And I don't want to replace my Customers `String`s with `StringProperty`-objects because the `SimpleStringProperty` is not `serializable` and I need the `Customer` to be transfered via RMI.)

I've tried the `BeanPathAdapter` from [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) (which looks really nice by the way) like this:

```
    BeanPathAdapter<MultipleSelectionModel> customerBeanPathAdapter;
    customerBeanPathAdapter = new BeanPathAdapter<>(lstCustomers.getSelectionModel());
    customerBeanPathAdapter.bindBidirectional("selectedItem.name", lblCustomerName.textProperty());
```

But this solution only throws me an Exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve accessor getSelectedItem
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle.buildAccessor(BeanPathAdapter.java:3062)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle.buildAccessorWithLikelyPrefixes(BeanPathAdapter.java:3022)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle.updateMethodHandles(BeanPathAdapter.java:2986)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle.<init>(BeanPathAdapter.java:2977)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldBean.performOperation(BeanPathAdapter.java:1348)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldBean.performOperation(BeanPathAdapter.java:1186)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter.bindBidirectional(BeanPathAdapter.java:567)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter.bindBidirectional(BeanPathAdapter.java:369)
at at.gs1.sync.qm.client.gui.MainWindowController.initialize(MainWindowController.java:61)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: symbolic reference class is not public: class javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel, from jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle
at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:512)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkSymbolicClass(MethodHandles.java:1113)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1094)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(MethodHandles.java:626)
at jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BeanPathAdapter$FieldHandle.buildAccessor(BeanPathAdapter.java:3049)
... 30 more
```

So I hoped there would be a better solution than to use `lstCustomers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)` and handle the population of the labels there manually.

Comment: Part of the problem is the access restricted implementation (looks like the adapter can't handle it). Another might be either a bug or invalid expectation (mine as well :-) - the value update seems to happen only in the direction from the bound property back to the adapted property (that is the path), not the other way round. At least couldn't make it work with the simplest of beans, neither one with fx-properties nor a plain core java bean property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution I think, to the one I gave before, is to use the BeanPathAdapter as you tried.
However the BeanPathAdapter needs to have the following property added to it:

```
private final ObjectProperty<B>  beanProp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
{
    beanProp.addListener( new ChangeListener<B>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends B> ob, B oldVal, B newVal )
        {
            setBean( newVal );
        }
    } );
}

public ObjectProperty<B> beanProperty()
{
    return beanProp; 
}
```

Then in your code you need the following:

```
BeanPathAdapter<Customer>  custBean;
custBean = new BeanPathAdapter<>( new Customer() );   // empty or any customer
custBean.bindBidirectional( "name", label.textProperty() );
custBean.beanProperty().bind( listview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty() );
```

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll give it a try today. Thanks! (btw. sorry for the late reply!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a simple one liner that you are looking for.
You could do the following:

```
label.textProperty().bind( Bindings.selectString( listview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(), "name" ) );
```

But you will need to modify your Customer POJO like so:

```
class Customer 
{
    private String name;
    ...
    public String getName() { return name;  }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return new SimpleStringProperty( name );
    }
}
```

I don't think this is recommended though because properties are expected to reflect changes in the underlying data and the above will only reflect the name as it was when nameProperty is called. So if setName is called the property won't reflect the change. If the Customer name never changes then you could get away with this.